# Extracting different parts of a string

Tags: r

I have strings of soccer games and I'm trying to break them down into individual parts in R. For example,

```
"Jun 0103:00 PMTottenham0 - 2Liverpool(0 - 1)" should return

"Jun 01", "3:00PM", "Tottenham", "0", "2", "Liverpool", "0", "1"
```

And

```
"May 0803:00 PMAjax2 - 3Tottenham(2 - 0)" should return

"May 08", "3:00PM", "Ajax", "2", "3", "Tottenham", "2", "0"
```

The goal is to get this into dataframe with headers

```
c("Date", "Time", "Home team", "Home team score", 
    "Away team score", "Away team", "Home team HT score", "Away team HT score")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tidyverse way...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

strings <- tibble(full = c("Jun 0103:00 PMTottenham0 - 2Liverpool(0 - 1)", 
                           "May 0803:00 PMAjax2 - 3Tottenham(2 - 0)"))

strings %>% mutate(date = str_extract(full, ".{6}"),
                   time = str_extract(full, "\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\s(AM|PM)"),
                   team_home = str_extract(full, "(AM|PM)[[:alpha:]]+"),
                   team_home = str_remove(team_home, "(AM|PM)"),
                   score_home = str_extract(full, "\\d+\\s-"),
                   score_away = str_extract(full, "-\\s\\d+"),
                   team_away = str_extract(full, "\\d[[:alpha:]]+"),
                   team_away = str_remove(team_away, "\\d"),
                   score_ht_home = str_extract(full, "\\(."),
                   score_ht_away = str_extract(full, ".\\)")) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("score")), str_extract, pattern = "\\d+") %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("score")), as.numeric) %>% 
  select(-full)
```

```
# A tibble: 2 x 8
  date   time     team_home score_home score_away team_away score_ht_home score_ht_away
  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>          <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>             <dbl>         <dbl>
1 Jun 01 03:00 PM Tottenham          0          2 Liverpool             0             1
2 May 08 03:00 PM Ajax               2          3 Tottenham             2             0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = c("Jun 0103:00 PMTottenham0 - 2Liverpool(0 - 1)", "May 0803:00 PMAjax2 - 3Tottenham(2 - 0)")
read.csv(header = FALSE,
         text = gsub("(^.{6})(.{8})(\\D+)(\\d+)\\s-\\s(\\d+)(\\D+)\\((\\d+)\\s-\\s(\\d+).*",
                     "\\1,\\2,\\3,\\4,\\5,\\6,\\7,\\8",
                     x))
#      V1       V2        V3 V4 V5        V6 V7 V8
#1 Jun 01 03:00 PM Tottenham  0  2 Liverpool  0  1
#2 May 08 03:00 PM      Ajax  2  3 Tottenham  2  0
```

Comment: Thanks! So I have similar strings such as "Mar 0603:00 PMAETFC Porto3 - 1(2 - 1)AS Roma(1 - 1)" but these have AET in them which represents "after extra time". I'm not interested in this so I want to get the same result as above but ignoring the "AET" and the "(2-1)" score in the middle.